# Change font-family in theme

Tags: theme

I am trying to change the font and the headings in theme 2016.

Do I need to edit the code?

The code says font-family sans-serif, I want it to be times-new-roman.

Comment: Welcome. Please explain what theme you are talking about and what CMS you are using. By itself, this question doesn't seem to be related to CiviCRM. It would also help to link to provide links to documentation and excerpts of the code you are referring to, but again, I stress, explain how this relates to CiviCRM.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is assuming you are referring to WP theme Twenty-Sixteen

Your question is not a CiviCRM issue, if you have other questions that are directly related to your CMS you should find a CMS specific forum to get more detailed help.

Here is a link with the instructions your are looking for.
https://www.geekypeak.com/how-to-change-fonts-for-twenty-sixteen-child-theme/
Again, you might need to find a CMS specific forum or try Google.